# Does there exist a Java library for the Zephyr protocol?

Tags: java, instant-messaging, pidgin

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyr_(protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyr_%28protocol%29)

Does there exist a Java library or some sort of Java implementation of the Zephyr protocol? I've tried using Google but haven't managed to find anything.

I guess I'm going to have to port it from barnowl/pidgin/adium or write an implementation from scratch if I don't manage to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zephyr has been replaced by [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol), which has a couple good Java implementations available. If you really need Zephyr I think you are right: you'll need to write your own library.

Comment: Where is this information about such replacement from? As I can see Jabber is a little different from Zephyr.

Comment: @FractalizeR The Wikipedia page is a good start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyr_(protocol)